# Matlab-GUI warning when using parfeval(): "Unable to save App Designer app object."

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to call parallel functions within my Matlab-GUI by pushing a startbutton.

For the beginning I tried to call one single function ("ReadTwinCAT") but I'm always getting the following error-message:

> "Warning: Unable to save App Designer app object. Save not supported
>   for matlab.apps.AppBase objects."

As I thought I already used parallel functions like this within a GUI, I don't know what I am doing wrong...

**Matlab-App-Designer Code:**

```
properties (Access = private)
    running_state = 0; % Description
    tcClient;
    db_conn;
end

methods (Access = private)

    function ReadTwinCAT(app)

        while app.running_state == 1
            disp('running')
            pause(0.1) 
        end  
        disp('stopped')

    end         
end


% Callbacks that handle component events
methods (Access = private)

    function StartButtonPushed(app, event)

       app.running_state = 1;

       pool = gcp(); %Initialize pool of workers

       parfeval(pool, @ReadTwinCAT, 0, app); %Call parallel function

    end
end
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, I think. My guess is that when you set a property of app like "app.running_state", that change has to be "saved" to update the app handle object, so that change is available to other functions that access the app object. I'm also guessing that in a parfeval call, such saving is not allowed because of thread safety problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found an answer from Mathworks staff:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366576-will-there-be-a-support-of-the-parallel-toolbox-in-matlab-app-designer#comment_720548

> Note the limitation of accessing the app object inside the parfor loop or any other functions called though Parallel Computing Toolbox.
>
> If you need to access properties of your app pass them down as values directly, e.g. instead of
>
> ```
> b = [0,0];  
> parfor i=1:2
>     b(i) = app.myprop*2
> end
> ```
>
> use
>
> ```
> tmp = app.myprop;
> b = [0,0];  
> parfor i=1:2
>     b(i) = tmp*2
> end
> ```

So it seems that you can't access (or it would seem set) the properties of the `app` object within a parallelized function. If you want to get data out, you'll probably have to set up a communication system using `parallel.pool.DataQueue`. Your example is tough to parallelize. A better option would probably be to add a listener to your `running_state` property, and/or use a `timer` function.

The major downside of this is that the function you call from the timer is not actually parallelized - it runs in the same thread, so if you have a lot of computation in `ReadTwinCAT`, I think it will cause lag/unresponsiveness in the GUI.

I've modified your code to use a timer instead of parfeval:

```
properties (Access = private)
    running_state = 0; % Description
    runningTimer;
    tcClient;
    db_conn;
end

methods (Access = private)

    function ReadTwinCAT(app, varargin)
        if app.running_state == 1
            disp('running')
        else
            stop(app.runningTimer);
            disp('stopped')
        end
    end

end

% Callbacks that handle component events
methods (Access = private)

    function StartButtonPushed(app, event)
        app.running_state = 1;

        app.runningTimer = timer;
        app.runningTimer.Period = 0.1;
        app.runningTimer.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
        app.runningTimer.TimerFcn = @app.ReadTwinCAT;
        start(app.runningTimer)
    end

end
```